# Is it necessary to unobserve the resizeObserver in useEffect cleanup in the following code?

Tags: reactjs, observable, use-effect

So this code watches a particular DOM node for height changes. The `resizeObserver` should run until the component is unmounted or the page changes. A colleague has suggested I might need to run `.unobserve` on that observer in the useEffect cleanup function. I had been assuming, as it is block scoped within useEffect and there are no other references to it, that it would simply be garbage collected at unmount - so I wouldn't need to manually `unobserve` anything.

Is my assumption correct or do I run the risk of creating a memory leak by not explicitly unobserving?

```
useEffect(() => {
    const spacerNode = document.getElementById('spacer');
    if (spacerNode) {
        const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver((entries) => {
            const rect = entries[0].contentRect;
            const { height } = rect;
            if (height !== offsetY) setOffsetY(height);
        });
        resizeObserver.observe(spacerNode);
    }
    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll, { passive: true });
    return () => {
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    };
}, []);
```

Comment: you should try it out: put a console.log inside the callback and see if it gets called on resize after the component was unmounted

Comment: Thanks @TobiasS. I tried that and it is not called, however that doesn't prove it is properly garbage collected and the memory freed. I strongly believe it should be but I'm not 100% certain.